Unity. Photon PUN2. Ожидание выполнения photon.Rpc
Я создаю кооператив на Unity и сталкиваюсь с проблемой при использовании удаленных вызовов. В конце игры игроки отправляют свои данные Мастер-клиенту, чтобы тот их обработал и на основе этого определил победителя, данные я отправляю с помощью photon.Rpc. И проблема заключается в том, что удаленные вызовы работают с определенной задержкой, что логично, и мне хочется как-то определять, когда именно игрок отправит данные, чтобы после этого уже начать их обрабатывать. Я имею что-то ввиду асинхронного подхода. В данный момент я использую задержку, чтобы дождаться, когда придут все данные, но меня полностью это не устраивает. Заранее спасибо!

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык
